# StandarScaler, sklearn get the different result from my own calculation?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, normalize

StandardScaler in `sklearn` is used to normalize the data by means of the formula: `x_normalize = (x-mean)/std`. However, I have a different result.

Here is my small example:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,2,3,4],
                  'Y': [1,2,4,72]})
StandardScaler().fit_transform(a)
```

The result is:

```
array([[-1.34164079, -0.6211513 ],
       [-0.4472136 , -0.58802323],
       [0.4472136 , -0.52176709],
       [ 1.34164079,  1.73094161]])
```

I try to calculate by myself:

```
a.loc[:,'X'].mean()
Out[61]: 2.5
a.loc[:,'X'].std()
Out[62]: 1.2909944487358056
(1-a.loc[:,'X'].mean())/a.loc[:,'X'].std()
Out[63]: -1.161895003862225
```

You can see that based on `StardardScale`, `a.loc[0,'X']` is `1`, then is `-1.3416` after transformation. But my result is `-1.1618`.
Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: I got std to be 1.118 and scaled value to be -1.34.

Comment: Thanks. But this means I have wrong result with a.loc[:,'X'].std(). How could this happen? Maybe I will try it on aonther IDE. Now I am using pycharm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas std and numpy std use different formula to calculate standard deviation. In pandas, they use:

```
sigma = sqrt(sum((X-X.mean())**2)/len(X-1))
```

But in numpy standard deviation is calculated as:

```
sigma = sqrt(sum((X-X.mean())**2)/len(X))
```

In scikit learn, they used numpy like standard deviation. So, both -1.34 and -1.16 is right, given that you are consistently using one formula.